# Direct proof for intervals in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $S$ be a non empty connected subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Prove that $S$ is an interval.

I have seen many proofs of this using contradiction. I'm just wondering if there is a direct proof for it without using contradiction.

Comment: Is there a direct definition of connected subset (that we can use here)?

Comment: Not really, I think, a connected subset is one in which the only subsets that are both open and closed are the empty set or the universal metric space.  Which I guess isn't actually direct as it's saying there is no proper clopen subset.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible.  Can try to set up a specific subset.  It's neither open nor closed so there must be a limit point not in it and an a point not an interior point of the subset.  Somehow conclude that the set was an Interval.  Don't see how to do that but maybe if we chose the subset properly....

Answer (score 1):

In case $S \subset \mathbb{R}$ is open (without its endpoints, which can be added later once we get the open interval). We can show, directly, that $S$ being *connected in $\mathbb{R}$ $\implies$ path-connected.*

Pick any $x_0$ in $S$ and define $P = \{x \in S: \text{ there is a continuous path from } x_0 \to x \}$. We show that $P$ and $S \setminus P$ are both open, but as $S$ is connected, $S = P$, i.e. is path connected.

Let $x_1 \in P$. Then $\exists \epsilon: (x_1 - \epsilon, x_1 + \epsilon) \subset S$ since $S$ is open, and if $x_2 \in (x_1 - \epsilon, x_1 + \epsilon)$ we can find a path from $x_0 \to x_1 \to x_2$. Hence $P$ is open.

Let $x'_2 \in S \setminus P$. Then $\exists \epsilon: (x'_2 - \epsilon, x'_2 + \epsilon) \subset S$. If $x'_1 \in  (x'_2 - \epsilon, x'_2 + \epsilon) \cap P$, then there would be path $x_0 \to x'_1 \to x'_2$, but $x'_2 \notin P$. Therefore, $(x'_2 - \epsilon, x'_2 + \epsilon) \in S \setminus P$. QED.

Now, taking the open interval between infimum and supremum  of $S$ (or $\pm \infty$) and showing inclusion, in both directions, will finish the proof.